# Ubuntu 18.04 python update problem

Tags: ubuntu, python, upgrade

I have an update problem for a few days. My version is **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS** (bionic)

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

gives an output like that;

> 

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnghttp2-14 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.6 libpython3.6-dev libpython3.6-minimal
  libpython3.6-stdlib python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3.6
  python3.6-dev python3.6-minimal
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 84,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77,8 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:14 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
Err:15 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.30.0-1ubuntu1+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-dev_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-dev_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-minimal_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nghttp2/libnghttp2-14_1.30.0-1ubuntu1+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 91.189.91.47 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` but this didn't solve the problem. What should I do?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

401 errors mean you need to provide a username and password (try visiting [the ESM pool](https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool) with your browser, you’ll see a prompt).

18.04 is now [out of standard support](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle), updates are only available with an [Expanded Security Maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) subscription.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I didn't know that. The problem is solved for me now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, here is a workaround for it that worked for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/748710/575373