# Ubuntu 18.04 Release Upgrade problem

Tags: ubuntu, lts

Upon reading [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/748500/ubuntu-18-04-python-update-problem) and its answer, I signed up for an Ubuntu Pro account and attached my machine using `sudo pro attach TOKEN`

I then ran `sudo apt update`, followed by `sudo apt upgrade` and continue to get the following unauthorized errors for all Python packages. Still getting the error message below:

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnghttp2-14 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib
  python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3.6 python3.6-minimal
13 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 esm-infra security updates
Need to get 38.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 79.9 kB disk space will be freed.
Err:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
Err:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.30.0-1ubuntu1+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-minimal_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nghttp2/libnghttp2-14_1.30.0-1ubuntu1+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I know 18.04 has reached End of Life (EoL), but this is an older desktop that doesn't get used or upgraded regularly, so it slipped by.

Any ideas on how to work around this so I can upgrade to the latest LTS release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a workaround while reading https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1990798

ran `pro disable esm-infra`

ran `apt-get upgrade` and saw that it no longer listed those packages.

ran `pro enable esm-infra`

ran `apt-get upgrade`, and now it will download the packages in question.

Answer (score 0):

After you have attached your token with `sudo pro attach`, you may need to disable esm first:

```bash
sudo pro disable esm-apps esm-infra
```

Then

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If you don't get a 401 error,  then enable esm:

```bash
sudo pro enable esm-apps esm-infra
```

then

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

That worked for my 18.04.